# Why does Azure scm show only one method?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have this code in my project that I uploaded to Azure Web Job.

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var host = new JobHost();
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }

        public static async Task AddSomethingAsync([QueueInput("myqueue1")] string _)
        {
  //....
        }


        public static async Task UpdateSomethingAsync([QueueInput("myqueue2")] string _)
        {
  //....
        }
    }
}
```

But it shows the first function "AddSomethingAsync" only in azure scm site (https://me.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/jobs/triggered/myjob/runs/201406170707442616)

Is it the known issue or Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it because two methods has same parameter type? I hope not. otherwise, it would be silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie. I got it now. I need to go to Functions page to see it. The default shows only the first method.